# Start ajax server script and poll for completeness

Tags: javascript, ajax, webmethod

I have an AJAX Request that takes a long time to complete executing. So long that it usually times out and just continues running on server. So I was thinking that if there was some way to just start it and occasionally poll the same request for completeness, that would be ideal.

So my question is can you run a server script, let it run, and poll occasionally to see if its completed? I'm using a web method to run on server if that helps/matters.

I don't want to store the data on a database so I cant just poll for the database so can I poll the script itself.

My fallback is however to create a temp table so I can call from it to see progress. Or is there some better way?

Comment: Can't you simple call it async and let the callback function inform you when it is complete?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Problem is depending on the size of the task it may times out.

Comment: If you are calling ASP.NET web service using script manager, you can supply second callback function that will be called in case of error including timeout.

Comment: Will this callback function be calling to the same request that is still running on server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly if you do not want your Ajax Request to timeout, you can use the 'timeout' attribute. 
XMLHttpRequest object used for Ajax calls has a 'timeout' attribute. Check out the documentation at http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-timeout-attribute .If you are making the Ajax call using jquery, you can simply do something like

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'your url',
  timeout: 100000 //this sets the timeout as 100 sec
  ……//your other attributes for the call
});
```

If you are interested in tracking your request progress, that might be a little difficult unless you want to track the completeness(complete), error, success or a particular status code. jquery provides different(complete, error, success and status code) properties for this. If you write a native ajax call(without query), the onreadystatechange event can track  the following.
0 - Unsent, 1- Opened, 2 - Response_Headers received, 3 - Loading(response is being received), 4 - Done. More at http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#event-handlers.
Tracking anything besides this would be for you to develop, maintain and monitor in your code I think.

Comment: Thanks this fixes my problem for now. As you mentioned though Ill have to find a cleaner way of bringing in all this data. I'm not too familiar with jquery so didn't know about timeout attribute. Thanks for the links as well.

Comment: Good to know. Just a minor correction, the timeout is in milliseconds so '100000' would be 100 sec and not 1 min. I have updated my answers.